# How do I structure my Python package?

Tags: python

I have most of my code in project.py which requires a second file, otherfile.py. Currently I'm just installing them as two separate modules with the same `setup.py` (with the py_modules variable) but I figured it's about time to package things up properly since project.py is growing and I may need split it up further.

The user only ever needs to interact with some classes and functions in project.py so in order to keep compatibility I wanted to use the following structure:

```
project/
    __init__.py  # (renamed from project.py)
    otherfile.py
```

However I've read that `__init__.py` should be kept almost empty. Another alternative would be:

```
project/
    __init__.py
    project.py
    otherfile.py
```

and to import everything from `project.py` that the user can see into `__init__.py` because I'd like to avoid adding an extra namespace for the user:

```
import project.project
```

I'm not sure it really matters but I'd like to do things 'The-Right-Way'.

Comment: I found [this website](http://guide.python-distribute.org/creation.html) to be helpful.

Comment: Kenneth Reitz's advice: https://medium.com/kr-projects/b8388ba7c1a

Comment: Kenneth Reitz is [no longer on medium.com](http://kennethreitz.org/why-i-left-medium/); [here is a working link](http://kennethreitz.org/repository-structure-and-python/) to that useful essay.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the second structure, but in your `__init__.py`, simply have...

```
from .project import PublicClass1
from .project import PublicClass2
from .project import PUBLIC_CONSTANT_A
...
```

Basically, only importing in `__init__.py` what you actually want to be public, while keeping `__init__.py` mostly free of code logic.